# Google Calendar - Private links removed - Any alternatives?

Tags: wordpress, google-calendar-api

I need to embed a google calendar onto a (wordpress) website that is password protected. However, it seems Google has recently removed the ability to get 'private links' and the only way to make a calendar embeddable is to either:

- Make it completely public, including to search engines etc (not a possibility)
- Make a google account for every user we want to have read access to the calendar and force them to login again to view the calendar (also not a particularly reasonable possibility)

Is there any way to embed a calendar whose settings are set to private? Or is there a viable alternative? We require collaborative and synchronized calendar access across a number of administrators and the ability to embed this data read-only to a website and still maintain the calendar's privacy to the full public.